# Update one column information

Tags: javascript, sql

I want to ask if I can update all the information in one column. The reason is that I'm doing a program and I've written javascript to make all the letters capital. But there are already entries in the given table and I want with another script all the entries in the column to be capitalized.The database is sql

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a database.

Comment: Your answer is: yes, I'm sure you can, and there's a few ways to tackle it.  A few questions for you:  What flavor of SQL is it?  This will potentially dictate the solution (if this is the route taken).  What have you tried?  What errors have you come across?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really too vague, but in general, to update data in a table you would use a SQL statement, something like this:  UPDATE tbl_name SET column_name=UPPER(column_name)

How to do this from Javascript is really another question.  Are you trying to do it from a webpage, node.js or what?  Do you need to send the data from your Javascript?  Again, nowhere near enough info for a complete answer.